# Django 1.11: combine fields for QuerySet using Q

Tags: python, django, datatable

I'm using the DataTable Plugin to render a list of reference for "nanas" (spanis for babysitters).  Right now I can filter on: nana's nombre(name) or reference's nombre(name).

In adition to this I want to filter on `nana's nombre + nana's apellido_paterno`

Doing this doesn't work (returns empty table, even if there should be a match):

```
if search_value:
    queryset = queryset.filter(
        Q(nana__nombre__icontains=search_value) & Q(nana__apellido_paterno__icontains=search_value),
        Q(nana__numero_de_documento__exact=search_value)
    )
```

Model:

```
class Referencia(models.Model):
    nombre_apellido = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=200)
    telefono = models.CharField(blank=False, null=False, max_length=15)
    correo = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    direccion = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    estado_referencia = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, choices=ESTADO_REFERENCIA, default=0)
    nana = models.ForeignKey(Nana)
    comentario = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=400)


def query_referencia_by_args(**kwargs):
    draw = int(kwargs.get('draw', None)[0])
    length = int(kwargs.get('length', None)[0])
    start = int(kwargs.get('start', None)[0])
    search_value = kwargs.get('search[value]', None)[0]
    order_column = kwargs.get('order[0][column]', None)[0]
    order = kwargs.get('order[0][dir]', None)[0]

    order_column = ORDER_COLUMN_CHOICES[order_column]
    # django orm '-' -> desc
    if order == 'desc':
        order_column = '-' + order_column

    queryset = Referencia.objects.all()
    total = queryset.count()

    if search_value:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            # Q(nombre_apellido__icontains=search_value) |
            Q(nana__nombre__icontains=search_value) | Q(nana__apellido_paterno__icontains=search_value) |
            Q(nana__numero_de_documento__exact=search_value)
        )

    count = queryset.count()
    queryset = queryset.order_by(order_column)[start:start + length]
    return {
        'items': queryset,
        'count': count,
        'total': total,
        'draw': draw
    }
```

EDIT 1:

After trying syntech answer I've modified my def to be, but doesn't filter anything.:

```
def query_referencia_by_args(**kwargs):
    draw = int(kwargs.get('draw', None)[0])
    length = int(kwargs.get('length', None)[0])
    start = int(kwargs.get('start', None)[0])
    search_value = kwargs.get('search[value]', None)[0]
    order_column = kwargs.get('order[0][column]', None)[0]
    order = kwargs.get('order[0][dir]', None)[0]

    order_column = ORDER_COLUMN_CHOICES[order_column]
    # django orm '-' -> desc
    if order == 'desc':
        order_column = '-' + order_column

    # queryset = Referencia.objects.all()


    queryset = Referencia.objects.annotate(combined_name=Concat(
        'nana__nombre',
        V(' '),
        'nana__apellido_paterno',
        output_field=models.CharField()
    )
    )

    total = queryset.count()

    if search_value:
        queryset.filter(combined_name__icontains=search_value)

        # queryset = queryset.filter(
        #     # Q(nombre_apellido__icontains=search_value) |
        #     Q(nana__nombre__icontains=search_value) | Q(nana__apellido_paterno__icontains=search_value) |
        #     Q(nana__numero_de_documento__exact=search_value)
        # )

    count = queryset.count()
    queryset = queryset.order_by(order_column)[start:start + length]
    return {
        'items': queryset,
        'count': count,
        'total': total,
        'draw': draw
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly how your code is not working the expected result?

Comment: It doesn't show any results, just an empty table.

Comment: With respect to the search value, when you say "In adition to this I want to filter on nana's nombre + nana's apellido_paterno" what exactly do you expect the results to be... I think you may want to use ORs rather than AND.

Comment: As you can see in my model I'm able to use OR and the filter works great for "nana__nombre" OR "nana__apellido_paterno" OR nana__numero_de_documento".  I would like to erase all of this, if I can filter: "nana__nombre" + "nana__apellido_paterno" (separated by a space).

Comment: Ah, I think I understand better now. I think what you might be wanting to do is use [f-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) for your filters.

Comment: Just a tip: never write code in your local language. Stick to English. If any developer will have to take over your code in the future, it will make it very difficult.

Comment: @sytech may you give, please, a complete answer? Thank you.

Comment: @OmarGonzales I'll formulate an answer, but I want to do some testing first. To be sure I have the concept well-understood... Let's say there is a babysitter whose name (`nana.nombre`) is `'Alice'` and her father's last name (`nana.apellido_paterno`) is `'Smith'` -- If the `search_value` is `'Alice Smith'`, a reference with this babysitter should be included in the query results, correct?  -- Perhaps it would also help to see the `Nana` model, but I think I understand well enough.

Comment: @sytech that's correct. Just to point out there should be at least one space " " between name and lastname.

Comment: The answer is a bit different than I imagined, but I actually got the desired result using annotations... Will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by filtering on an annotation.

First, create an annotation for a field, `combined_name` that represents the combination of `nana__nombre` and `nana__apellido_paterno` separated by a space. We do this using `objects.annotate`, the `Concat` function.

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.db.models import Value as V

qs = Referencia.objects.annotate(combined_name=Concat(
                                               'nana__nombre',
                                               V(' '),
                                               'nana__apellido_paterno',
                                               output_field=models.CharField()
                                               )
                                 )
```

We can filter against this qs using the `combined_name` "field" we annotated to get the result. Using the scenario I described, let's test it out...

```
search_value = 'Alice Smith'
results = qs.filter(combined_name__icontains=search_value)

a = results.first()
print(a.nana.nombre)
# 'Alice'
print(a.nana.apellido_paterno)
# 'Smith'
```

Edit: had a small bug from transcription error.

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it first thing in the morning.